# There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference

Tags: visual-studio-2015

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "x86".
>   This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the
>   targeted processor architecture of your project through the
>   Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>   between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>   references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project.

Estou com este erro quando dou build no meu projeto. Oque pode ser? Nunca tive este erro.

Comment: Como assim? ...

Comment: Veja se isso responde sua pergunta:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/how-do-i-fix-the-visual-studio-compile-error-mismatch-between-processor-archit. Uma outra solução seria compilar em x64 ao invés de x86, possivelmente não irá ocorrer esse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi,  fui em cada projeto, botão direito depois Properties e mudei a versão do Net Framework que estava 4.0 para 4.5.1 e funcionou.